# Show that $f _ a $ is a Homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

For a
fixed element $a$ is a group $G$, define $$f _ a (x) = a ^ {−1} xa , x \in G$$

Show that $f _ a $ is a Homomorphism.

I know that to show that a mapping $f:G \rightarrow G'$, Where $G$ and $G'$ are two groups with $\#$ and  $*$  as their binary compositions I have to show that $$f (a\#b) = f(a) * f(b)$$ 
But I cannot understand how to do that here.

Comment: Well, what do you get when you insert the definitions?

Comment: So you are asking if the map $f_a:G\rightarrow G$ is an homomorphism?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft What is an antihomomorphism ? How can I show this a homomorphism if it is a antihomomorphism?

Comment: @Myself I can see that you have deleted the comment which stated about product operation. So is the answer I have marked right is not valid?

Comment: @isuru-buddhika The answer marked valid is 100% correct.

Comment: @MySelf Ok. Thanks

Comment: @Myself I want to clarify something. You said something about product operation in the group $G$. Is that what is being applied in the answer?

Comment: @isuru-buddhika The point that I wanted to make was that you should ask yourself: I have a map $f : G \to G'$ and I want to show that it is a morphism _what are the operations that I should consider on G and G'_ In your case, we have $f_a : G \to G$ and the operation is twice the group law on $G$. So you must show that $f_a(xy) = f_a(x)f_a(y)$. The answer below can be found by realising that this is what you must show, expanding both left and right side using the definition of $f_a$ and manipulating both hands until you have proven that they are equal. (Which is quite easy as it turns out.)

Comment: @Myself So you are saying that I should decide what operation to use (As no operation is given in the question)to show that it is a homomorphism?

Comment: @isuru-buddhika Yes you cannot show that a map is a morphism if you do not decide first what operations you want to consider. Most of the time (like here) there is only one choice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{align}
f_a(xy)&=a^{-1}xya\\
&=a^{-1}xeya \\
&=a^{-1}xaa^{-1}ya\\
&=f_a(x)f_a(y)
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

Himt : inf $f(ab)=g^{-1}abg$ then $f(ab)=g^{-1}agg^{-1}bg=f(a)f(b)$